# Xamarin Forms - GIF stored put into WebView

Tags: xamarin.forms, gif

I was asking myself about it and I can't find something interesting on the web. I never worked with `WebView` but I found some things about it and ti seems possible to create its own `WebPage`.

Then is it possible to create a `WebPage` (In the `WebView`) and **put into this `WebView` (or `WebPage`) a GIF?**

I also understand, I think, that I can link the `WebView` to the *GIF's link* on the Web, but for data exchange, **I would like to store it on the phone instead of load it each time.**

***So, is it possible?***

Thank in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Xamarins [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/webview/):

```
// define a interface
public interface IBaseUrl { string Get(); }

// load html
var html = new HtmlWebViewSource ();
html.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl> ().Get ();

htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
    <head>
    <link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""default.css"">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
    <p>The CSS and image are loaded from local files!</p>
    <img src='Images/XamarinLogo.png'/>
    </body>
    </html>";

webView.Source = html;
```

You will then need to implement IBaseUrl for each platform you wish to support.  For iOS, it would look like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (BaseUrlWebView), typeof (BaseUrlWebViewRenderer))]
namespace WorkingWithWebview.iOS {
    public class BaseUrlWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer  {
        public override void LoadHtmlString (string s, NSUrl baseUrl)  {
            baseUrl = new NSUrl (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, true);
            base.LoadHtmlString (s, baseUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but it can works as easy as you shown for a GIF file? do not forget that this GIF is an animation and not a simple image

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't.  But you would have to test it to be sure.

Comment: Hi, I made it months ago, sorry if I didn't come back to valid your answer.. It worked perfectly but not anymore and I don't know why.. https://github.com/Emixam23/XamarinByEmixam23/tree/master/Detailed%20Part/Controls/GifProject Can you take a look please?